# Jquery login popup form closed when clicking on submit

Tags: php, jquery, popup

I created an popup login form in Jquery. and working fine. but when in clicked on the submit button the popup hides and the error to show the message like `wrong username and password` is displayed when i open the login popup form  again. I want the popup form remain open if there is a error message.

```
$(function () {
    // Calling Login Form
    $("#login_form").click(function () {
        $(".social_login").hide();
        $(".user_login").show();
        return false;
    });

    // Calling Register Form
    $("#register_form").click(function () {
        $(".social_login").hide();
        $(".user_register").show();
        $(".header_title").text('Register');
        return false;
    });

    // Going back to Social Forms
    $(".back_btn").click(function () {
        $(".user_login").hide();
        $(".user_register").hide();
        $(".social_login").show();
        $(".header_title").text('Login');
        return false;
    });

})
```

Comment: You'll need to show us some code

Comment: can you show us the popup modal DOM, and are you using any plugin for the popup?

Comment: i am using this tutorial                 http://www.andwecode.com/create-popup-login-and-signup-form/

Comment: show us your submit function!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            <?php if ($error == 'true'): ?>
                $("#popup-login").modal('show');       
            <?php endif ?>
    });
</script>
```

in your controller, after authentication set a a error flag as true so that if error occur modal will remain open even page refresh